# How to have live wallpaper open directly from the market?

Tags: android, google-play, live-wallpaper

Is it possible to configure my project manifest, so that when a user presses "open" on the android market, my live wallpaper is applied straight away? Some users don't seem capable of figuring out that they need to apply a wallpaper after install.

Comment: In the worst case, you can always include an Activity with the MAIN/LAUNCHER intent-filter that sets the wallpaper and then exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike a static wallpaper, live wallpapers cannot be set programmatically, so the user will need to select it from the live wallpaper gallery manually. So all you can do really is add some instructions to your wallpapers description on the Android Market or add an Activity that will show an instruction popup and direct you to the live wallpaper gallery.

Comment: Is it really possible to set wallpaper now when Jelly Bean is here? Can you please check this one out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683464/set-live-wallpaper-programmatically-on-rooted-device-android